# get specific characters of a String

Tags: android, string

I need to extract specfic information of a String. So I have to create two new Strings with the necessary information isolated.

The structure of the String: `{line1=necessary information 1, line2=necessary information 2}`

As you can see, I need the String values (necessary information 1: after '=' and before ',' and necessary information 2)

This is the String:

```
 String telefonname_nummer =  listview.getItemAtPosition((int) position).toString();
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: split with `, ` then `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    String yourInfo = "line1=necessary information 1, line2=necessary information 2";
    String[] parts = yourInfo.split(",");

    String info1 = parts[0].split("=")[1];
    String info2 = parts[1].split("=")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this way may help you**

```
  String urString = "line1=necessary information 1, line2=necessary information 2";

  // First split your string with ","
  String[] splitedString = urString.split(",");

  //as u mention in Qestion u want string after "=" 
  //so,

  String firstString = splitedString [0].split("=")[1];
  String scndString  = splitedString [1].split("=")[1];

  Log.e("firstString ",firstString );
  Log.e("scndString",scndString);
```